# translate innerhtml with dynamic value in ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4, innerhtml, translate

I want to translate array of string in innerHTML

I had define my en and fr json in assest. it works fine on normal label

but its a problem with InnerHTML

Code

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let d of diseases; let i=index" text-wrap (click)="toggleGroup(i)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i)}">

<ion-label text-wrap>
  <h2>{{d.title | translate }}</h2>
        <p *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)" [innerHTML]= "'d.description' | translate" ></p>

   </ion-label>
```

**d.title** translate successfully.
but **d.description** not working as i am expected

Comment: If my answer doesn't help then please update to be clear about "not working as expected" - does it display untranslated? with html encoded wrong? nothing at all?

Answer (score 0):

While looking for an answer I found [this issue](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/914), which has an example that means you probably got the syntax right:

```
<div [innerHTML]="'firstname-optional' | translate"></div>
```

Which makes me think maybe you have actually got some other problem.

Is the `d.description` definitely correct?

And it has a value for the one you are checking?

Does it work if you actually test it as something thats not `innerHTML`?

Comment: Have you confirmed `d.description` is populated as you expect it to be with something like: `<h2>{{d.description | translate }}</h2>`